# Is a dash acceptable in the context of this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation

In [Capitalization of first letter after a dash](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/5817/54) , it was claimed (with some citations supplied)

> Where are the rules that even say a dash is permissible in a sentence
>   like "I'm in South Ossetia - yes, I managed to get a visa!"?

While I myself would say "I'm in South Ossetia. Yes, I managed to get a visa!", using a dash seems ok to me. I suspect such a conversational style would be frowned upon in formal writing, but that's a separate issue.

Is there a consensus against using the dash this way?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.talkenglish.com/Grammar/interjections.aspx) is as good a summary as any...

> An interjection is a word expressing some kind of emotion. It can be used as filler. Interjections do not have a grammatical function in the sentence and are not related to the other parts of the sentence.
>    *If an interjection is omitted, the sentence still makes sense. It can stand alone.* (italics mine).

I suggest that in OP's example, "yes" is an interjection. So if we remove it, we're left with...

"I'm in South Ossetia [?] I managed to get a visa!"

...where I've left [?] in there because it's not obvious which of the original punctuation marks were part of the interjection. You'll note from the link above that in all their examples, the interjection is a *capitalised word followed by an exclamation mark*.

I see no reason for OP to deviate from that pattern. The original should have been...

> "I'm in South Ossetia. Yes! I managed to get a visa!"

...in which case there would be no problem in removing the interjection...

> "I'm in South Ossetia. I managed to get a visa!"

In principle, the period in that final version could perhaps be a dash. But in practice hardly anyone would write *"Yes! - I did it!"*, so if we're going to be consistent, "chatty" dashes aren't really helpful.

---

TL;DR: Don't use dashes in the first place. Stick to the standard orthography. Capitalise the first letter of the interjection, and follow it by an exclamation mark (or period). So you *could remove it* if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

*Comma Sense, a fun-damental guide to punctuation* suggests to use a dash to signify a sudden change of thought, or before the citation of an author or the source of a quotation. (It has a part about using dashes in pairs that I will not quote.)

> She loves me, she loves me not, she loves me, she loves me not—then again, what I am doing asking the opinion of a flower?

> We are going to—what's that burning smell?

> This is the best present we have ever received. I can't believe the Greeks went through all this trouble. This wooden horse is huge. And it is so *easy*, isn't it? That is because it's made so well. It's about the time that—hey, did you just hear the horse *giggle*?

In the last example, the dash is used before an interjection, but the purpose of the dash is still to signify a sudden change of thought.

Comment: I don't see how this helps in OP's specific case - where personally, I think the dash is *not* appropriate. Arguably because it's not a "sudden chane of thought". It's an *explanation/expansion*.

Comment: That is my point: There are just two cases where a single dash should be used, and neither of them applies to the example given from the OP.

Comment: I don't really disagree with anything you say, but take, for example, [Abby gave me a terrible haircut—and she expected a tip!](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-a-Dash-in-an-English-Sentence). Or [And he must've thought — Wow. What had he thought?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/is-a-dash-acceptable-in-the-context-of-this-sentence/5845?noredirect=1#comment8962_5845). Are either or both of those "wrong"? It's still not that obvious to me that you're actually saying OP's dash is incorrect.